# Where can I find a dataset of albums labeled with their release date, band name, genre, and number of sold copies?

Tags: data-request, music

I am looking for find datasets of albums labeled with:

- their release date
- band name
- genre (e.g. rock, pop, etc.)
- number of sold copies (ideally per country, otherwise worldwide)

Comment: band name and genre can be obtained from freedb.org (the fork made when CDDB (now GraceNote) went commercial).  They might have release date, but I doubt they have anything about sales.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can find an API based on the answers to [the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731250/anyone-know-of-a-music-api-and-database).

It may be harder to find the number of copies sold, so you may need to collect from two sources and join them together. In particular, the API listing site [ProgrammableWeb](http://www.programmableweb.com/apitag/music) lists many music APIs.

Answer (score 2):

columbia has a music database here: http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/millionsong/pages/example-track-description
also i'm willing to bet last.fm does too